# Attach script to element after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am building an ASP.Net Web API application for users to create to-do items. After making a GET request for a list of a user's items, I am trying to attach a particular function when a certain element is clicked.

In the GET request (done in a separate file), the following is appended to the `todo-list` div found in the main page:

```
$('<div class="single-todo"> +
  '<div class="td-delete"><div class="delete-todo" title="Delete" data-id="' + id + '" data-username="' + username + '"></div></div>' +
  '<div class="td-title">' + title + '</div>' + 
  '</div>').appendTo('#todo-list');
```

In the main page, I am trying to attach a function when the `delete-todo` div is clicked, namely: (this is put in the `.ready()` function)

```
$(".delete-todo").on('click', function () {
    var username = $(this).data("username");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    DeleteTodo(id, username);
});
```

(Here, `DeleteTodo()` is a function within a js file). When the `delete-todo` div is clicked it is never called, and the only possibility is that the `delete-todo` div doesn't exist at first (it only exists once the AJAX call is done).

How can I attach the function call to be executed after the AJAX call, without the need to make the same function through inline code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic elements like this, I would recommend event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', ".delete-todo", function () {
    //...
});
```

That will attach the handler to the `document` and you won't need to worry about binding to new elements.

Answer (score 1):

Add the function call in the success call back of the ajax call,so whenever the ajax call returns a 200 status the function will be executed